# window.scrollY value is controlled by wrong ScrollBar

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar

I'm trying to integrate a scroll bar to a dynamic table after the height is 275px.  The scroll bar is functional after the table reaches 275px, however, when I use the table scroll bar, I do not see any change to the window.scrollY value.  Instead, The scroll bar for the entire page is changing the value of window.scrollY, which is not what I need.

Here is a snippet of my table container:

```js
// Define Table Container and add it to the parent container
var tableContainer = $('<div>').css({
  'max-width': '55px',
  'max-height': '275px',
  'overflow-y': 'scroll',
  'border': '1px solid black', // Add a border for visualization
});


let scrollPosition = 0;

function handleScroll() {
  scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  console.log("PosY = ", scrollPosition);
}

let my_array = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6]
];

// Function to update and display the 'result'
function updateAndDisplayResult() {
  // Loop through your data and populate the table
  my_array.forEach(function(subArray) {
    var row = $('<tr>'); // Create a row for each sub-array

    subArray.forEach(function(item) {
      var cell = $('<td>').text(item);
      cell.css('border', '1px solid black'); // Add cell border
      row.append(cell);
    });

    tableContainer.append(row); // Append the row to the table
  });

  // Finally, append the tableContainer to your document
  $('#result').append(tableContainer);
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)

updateAndDisplayResult();
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

I've attached a few pictures to better clarify as well:

[image: Wrong Scroll bar affects window.scrollY]

[image: Scroll always enabled by default]

I've tried many things, but I'm stuck here.  Any solutions to the following would be greatly appreciated:

1. Link table scroll bar scrolly to window.scrollY value
2. Hide scroll bar until the max-height defined.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i've removed the border on the table, since it keeps showing up even without the scrollbar, and the scrollbar is perfectly visible when it's needed.

To display the table scrollbar just when it's needed, instead of using
`'overflow-y': 'scroll',` you can use `'overflow-y': 'auto',`.

The scrollPosition problem, is that you've attached it to the window, instead of the table in question.

I've changed the `scrollY` to the `scrollTop()` function and your `addEventListener` to listen for the scroll action, for a `.on('scroll')`.

Now it'll work as expected:

```js
// Define Table Container and add it to the parent container
var tableContainer = $('<div>').css({
  'max-width': '55px',
  'max-height': '275px',
  'overflow-y': 'auto',
});


let scrollPosition = 0;

function handleScroll() {
  scrollPosition = tableContainer.scrollTop();
  console.log("PosY = ", scrollPosition);
}

let my_array = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6]
];

// Function to update and display the 'result'
function updateAndDisplayResult() {
  var cScroll = tableContainer.scrollTop(); //Store the value
  // Loop through your data and populate the table
  my_array.forEach(function(subArray) {
    var row = $('<tr>'); // Create a row for each sub-array

    subArray.forEach(function(item) {
      var cell = $('<td>').text(item);
      cell.css('border', '1px solid black'); // Add cell border
      row.append(cell);
    });

    tableContainer.prepend(row); // Add the new rows on top instead
  });

  tableContainer.scrollTop(cScroll); // Set the scroll back

  // Finally, append the tableContainer to your document
  $('#result').append(tableContainer);
};

tableContainer.on('scroll', handleScroll)

updateAndDisplayResult();
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That did the trick.  One more thing.  The reason for all this was so I can keep track of the scroll position, so if the user scrolls the table down a bit and a new element is added to the top of the table, I can hold the position and prevent it from jumping to the top to display the new element.  I thought I could use this "window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);" now that my scrollPosition is working correctly, but the position is still jumping to the top.  I tried adding this in a few different places in updateAndDisplayResult() but all the same result.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can create a variable to store the current possition of the table before the new element is added, and then you can set the position again to the value after you add a new element: `var cScroll = tableContainer.scrollTop();`, i'll try to work it out and edit the response.

Answer (score 0):

just add 'tableContainer.scrollTop(scrollPosition)' to the function named 'handleScroll' last line

or tableContainer.get(0).scrollTo({top: scrollPosition})

this is the sample code to sync scrolling is:

```js
// Define Table Container and add it to the parent container
var tableContainer = $('<div>').css({
  'max-width': '55px',
  'max-height': '275px',
  'overflow-y': 'scroll',
  'border': '1px solid black', // Add a border for visualization
});


let scrollPosition = 0;

function handleScroll() {
  scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  var tableScrollEl = tableContainer.get(0);
  var docScrollEl = document.scrollingElement;
  var docScrollHeight = docScrollEl.scrollHeight - docScrollEl.clientHeight
  var tableScrollHeight = tableScrollEl.scrollHeight - tableScrollEl.clientHeight;
  var scale = tableScrollHeight / docScrollHeight
  console.log("PosY = ", scrollPosition);
  tableScrollEl.scrollTo({top: scrollPosition * scale})
  //tableContainer.scrollTop(scrollPosition)
}

let my_array = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6]
];

// Function to update and display the 'result'
function updateAndDisplayResult() {
  // Loop through your data and populate the table
  my_array.forEach(function(subArray) {
    var row = $('<tr>'); // Create a row for each sub-array

    subArray.forEach(function(item) {
      var cell = $('<td>').text(item);
      cell.css('border', '1px solid black'); // Add cell border
      row.append(cell);
    });

    tableContainer.append(row); // Append the row to the table
  });

  // Finally, append the tableContainer to your document
  $('#result').append(tableContainer);
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)

updateAndDisplayResult();
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```